# How much has dynamic range improved since the EOS 20D?

Tags: canon, dslr, dynamic-range

I've owned the 20D since 2004 and my main criticism is it's dynamic range compared to print film (which I preferred to slide film because of difficulties shooting dark/light scenes).

Can anyone tell me how much of an improvement the latest technology is (eg 7D) and whether full frame sensors are much better again? Using this site http://www.dxomark.com, it looked like there isn't significant improvement (not what i wanted to hear) so I thought I would ask people about real life usage.

Thanks!

Comment: Any current full frame camera, plus quite a few APS-C ones as well, will blow the doors off the 20D for dynamic range (amongst other things) at this point. As Itai noted, the K-5 is an APS-C which exceeds the DR of medium format and the Nikon D7000 isn't far behind. The 20D is a good camera, but the current lineup of all major players exceeds it.

Comment: Excellent question.  Not many people seem to consider this when looking at new cameras.

Comment: My view on this seems a bit controversial, and it is more on overall image quality, not so much DR: From what Ive seen in real photos (not lab tests) is that digital cameras evolved rapidly up to 2009 with the introduction of cmos microlenses. Since that it is mostly on the feature side they improved. The thing is that images from older cameras have a lot of noise in the dark areas, visible even on downscaled images, while newer cameras 2009+ has noise if you view at 100% crops, but it goes away when you print/resize for screen. I assume you are not printing A0 posters.

Comment: pixelpeeping high iso tests between canon and the sony based cameras, you see a mnarginally smoother result from the sony based cameras but it is also less detailed. http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/pentaxk5/20. try iso 6400. Very small differences.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you don't call 3 EV significant? I would say, it is, but it is subjective. Even
one EV is a big, step as it represents twice the contrast for each additional stop.

DxOMark says the DR of the Canon 20D is 11 EV while the Pentax K-5, which is the top model in terms of DR now, shows 14.1 EVs. There are a few models that capture above 13 EVs.

**EDIT:** With respect to full-frame vs non-full-frame, the current state is that besides the Nikon D3X, the top performers in terms of dynamic-range are either cropped-sensor (Pentax K-5, Nikon D7000, Fuji S5, etc) or medium-formats.

Side note: You may notice that it took years of improvements in conventional sensor design to catch up with the Fuji S5 Pro.

Comment: Thanks for reply - we must be looking at different data, this link...

http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/en/Camera-Sensor/Compare-sensors/(appareil1)/281%7C0/(appareil2)/619%7C0/(onglet)/0/(brand)/Canon/(brand2)/Canon

...says 11EV (20D) Vs 11.7EV (7D) - even 13EVs would sound like a fair improvement.

Comment: @Steve - DR is only one aspect. High ISO performance, shutter speeds, frame rates, and a lot more go into the difference if you compare the 20D to something like the 7D. Having said that, if you aren't feeling limited by the 20D and you enjoy what you see, then why change? Any and all upgrades should be compelling, otherwise it's just an never-ending cycle.

Comment: @Steve - You just chose a poor example. DxOMark shows you the ranking of all sensors, so you do not even have to guess which camera ranks higher in any metric. Here is the link of cameras ordered by dynamic range: http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/en/Camera-Sensor/Sensor-rankings/(type)/usecase_landscape

Comment: Thanks John - I pretty much only feel limited by the 20D in terms of DR, but all the extras you mention would be bonuses. I'm really trying to get a feel for whether the 7D would rectify the only big issue I have.

Comment: @Itai - thanks, that link is much clearer - it does just show that the increase in DR in the canon range over 6 years is minimal, especially when you look at the same graph for Nikon and Pentax.

Comment: @Canon Are you seeing this, please bring out a 1DsIV that wins, thanks.

Comment: @Itai with regards to full frame vs. non-full frame, DXO mark measure dynamic range at the base ISO and this figure is dominated by read noise, which is how the newer crops like the K-5 achieve 14 stops. Dynamic range in low light at high ISO is dominated by photon noise, here the larger sensor has an advantage by capturing more photons, so you'd expect to see full frame (and MF) with an advantage here. Shame DXO mark don't measure this.

Comment: @Matt - I know and they do. The trouble I always have with DxOMark is that it boils down each thing to one number. If you compare the DR of the K-5, S5 Pro and 1Ds Mark III you can that the K-5 is superior at DR at ALL ISO sensitivities. This not the case of the K-5 vs S5 Pro. See for yourself: http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/en/Camera-Sensor/Compare-sensors/(appareil1)/676%7C0/(appareil2)/511%7C0/(appareil3)/436%7C0/(onglet)/0/(brand)/Pentax/(brand2)/Fujifilm/(brand3)/Canon - Click on the Dynamic Range tab to see what I am referring to.

Comment: @Itai - Fuji has to be doing something weird, that curve is bizarre! Most comparisons I've ever run have had a generally straight line down the DR graph as ISO increases. So, how the heck does Fuji go up before going down?

Comment: @Steve - the 7D is a very good camera, I know several people that use it and it performs very well. Having said that, when it comes to dynamic range and high ISO performance in an APS-C camera, then Pentax and Nikon are clearly head and shoulders above Canon. Is it worth a brand switch? I doubt it, the 7D is very good, so I'd expect that you'd seldom, if ever, really see the difference.

Comment: @John - I guess you are not familiar with Fuji's SuperCCD SR. It is an amazing piece of technology that became legendary among wedding photographers. The sensor has two sizes of photosites and one of each size is used for each pixel. The smaller one is less sensitive and catches highlights, the larger is for most other details. Since they clip at different points, the interaction is odd. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_CCD (The S5 Pro uses the SR II)

Comment: @John - It depends on your perception. I do agree that the 7D is a good camera but I saw the difference very clearly. I had the 7D for a one month review period (http://www.neocamera.com/review.php?id=169) and have had the K-5 for a little more. Both great but the DR is easily noticeable when shooting outdoors. The 7D's less conservative metering does not help it either for that. But if I had to shoot sports, the 7D would be better due to its continuous autofocus (AF-C). I still use a 50D for action and a K-5 for landscape and architecture.

Comment: @Itai thanks for posting the DR vs ISO graph, don't know why I've never clicked that tab before! The gap to the 1Ds3 closes a lot as the ISO goes up but the k-5 stays ahead, that is interesting!

Comment: Remember that what we perceive is the +3 above the "11" contrast, not the x2^3 contrast, just like doubling the amplitude in audio sounds only marginally louder if it is already pretty loud (which 11EV is since the screens cant even show that much).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've noticed much more fine detail in shadows and highlights when I upgraded from the 20D to the 5D mk II. Of course, the increas is only beneficial until you display the images on screen - whilst you consider the current range of sensors use 14 bit depth to capture the intensity of each colour component in the image, graphics cards only work to 8 bits per channel; obviously if you're printing, then you can use the luxury of 16 bits per channel, but you're stil going to be limited by the colour gamut of your printer.

The extended bit depth is especially useful if you shoot in RAW mode, and you need to do some exposure compensation off camera. The later cameras are a lot more forgiving than the 20D is, but it is still better to get it right "in camera".